# Finding value in a CSV file and comparing with today's date

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I'm trying to get a value from a CSV file.

> If today's date = DateInCSVFile give the "key" value.

Keys.csv

```
Guest,Key
1-Jun,OIOMY-ZFILZ
2-Jun,LSSJC-PDEUL
3-Jun,MQNVJ-TETLV
4-Jun,HCJIJ-ECVPY
5-Jun,SPACR-AJSLU
6-Jun,MEURS-UQTVX
```

Code:

```
$today = Get-Date -format dd-MMM
$keys = import-csv c:\office\keys.csv -Header @(1..2)
$data = $keys | ? { $_.1 -match $today}
Write-Host $data.2
```

I tried the `foreach` and `if` commands. Nothing worked.

Comment: If the day in your file has only one place, use `$today = Get-Date -format d-MMM` otherwise the leading zero in $today won't match

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of options. If you want something quick and dirty, try:

```
$stuff = Import-Csv -Path .\stuff.csv 

foreach ($thing in $stuff) {
    if ( $thing.Guest  -eq $(Get-date -Format 'd-MMM') ) {
        Write-Output $thing.Key
    }
}
```

I import the CSV file's contents to a variable. I iterate over each line. If the day in Guest matches the current day, I output the key

Comment: OPs code works fine, once changing the date format to `d-MMM` as your code does also.

Comment: That's a good point about preceding zero's. Made me think about two digit days e.g., 12, 22, etc. I modified my answer to account. Good looking out @LotPings!

Comment: Change rolled back :-)

Answer (score 0):

The **only problem with your code is your date format, `dd-MMM`**, as [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) observes:

It creates `0`-left-padded numbers for single-digit days such as `6`, whereas the dates in the CSV have no such padding.

Thus, changing `Get-Date -format dd-MMM` to `Get-Date -format d-MMM` (just `d` instead of `dd`) should fix your problem.

However, given that you're reading the entire file into memory anyway, you can **optimize the command** to (PSv4+):

```
$today = Get-Date -Format d-MMM
(Import-Csv c:\office\keys.csv).Where({ $_.Guest -eq $today }).Key
```

Also note that the purpose of `-match` is to perform *regular-expression*-based matching, not (case-insensitive) *string equality*; use `-eq` for the latter.